# Using Julia to solve the student final project allocation problem

Tags: julia, allocation

I am doing a project that I have to use Julia code to solve a student's final project allocation problem. I am kind of new to this kind of coding and new for Julia. I need some help with this.

Start with the problem, I have data for students and projects.

For students, I have 137 students who come from 4 different majors(such as, EE, ME, BIOM and EMGT). For every student, they have chosen 10 projects that they want to work on in Rank. (For example, student 1 want to do project 10, 1, 5....)

On the project side, I have 3 pieces of information.
1, all project has their request for the student(For example, project A need EE student but other major does not require).
2, All project has a priority rank from 1 to 4. 1 is the most important and 4 is the less.
3, the Most project has funding. But Funding does not relate to the priority. For example, project A has $20,000 as funding, but the priority level is 2. Project B may not have any funding, but it is priority 1. In this case, I have to make sure the project B has the right student, but project A is less important.

For all students, they can only get into one project.
In this project, I have to make sure that all priority 1 projects get the right student and try to make sure most students get into their first rank of project.
For now, I have loaded the student and project information in Julia as :
[load student and project inform][1]

The workspace looks like this.
[Data is the student inform, I only pice the top 4 of student rank of project][2]

I am looking for to get the solution of this project. Like array for all studnet allocation. And plot the data like how many studnet's project is their first pick.

If possible, please give me some idea about how to work on the next. If there is a close example of Julia code will be great.

Thank you for your time and help.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMeEb.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9YJ5.png

Comment: This looks to be a mixed integer linear programming problem. Have a look at JuMP and MILP solvers. This is a good theoretical introduction https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7tzFRIiseJI&t=446s   Note that from 2018 API has slightly changed so after watching this watch some 2020 JuMP video to understand the current API.